# How to extend classes properly for a local directory site?

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP and working on a local directory site where you can search local shops and companies. I have to make some classes like `string_class`(which will deal with strings) ,`city_class`(which will deal with city),`state_class`(which will deal with state),`category_class`(which will deal with company category) and `company_class`(which will deal with company). Now I'm confused about where to start and where to end for using a real concept of OOP.

Let's think that I have to make these five classes

```
<?php 
class string_class(){

}

class city_class(){

}

class state_class(){

}

class category_class(){

}

class company_class(){

}      `
?>
```

Now do you think should i extend string class for making city class ?? 
like

```
class city_class extends string_class{
// DO SOME CITY STUFF HERE
}
```

and then

```
class state_class extends city_class{
// DO SOME STATE STUFF HERE
}
```

and then

```
class company_class extends state_class{
// DO SOME COMPANY STUFF HERE
}
```

Comment: Google: "favor composition over inheritance"

Comment: @JohnConde  I googled "composition over inheritance" ~ fascinating what I discovered so thanks for that

Comment: Each class should have a purpose and a clearly defined role and I am not sure you are sure what each of your classes will do. If you are not sure don't use inheritance. You might need composition.

Comment: @Andreas i'm sure what my classes will do,like city class will validate city name and get city name,city id from database etc.... and company class will validate company name and fetch company name,city,address,category whenever i required but the problem is that i want to do it by using real concept of OOP.

Comment: OK then, what's keeping you from using inheritance? If you know WHY you are inheriting go on and inherit from your base class.

Comment: @JohnConde Yeah i was thinking so ,i should use composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] about where to start and where to end for using a real concept of OOP

You need to identify the invariants of your class; that is, conditions that must always be true for instances of the class. In your example, you want to prevent creation of `city_class` objects that do not have correct city names. So--

```
class city_class {
    function __construct($name) {
        if (!$this->validate_city($name)) 
            throw new city_exception();
    }
}
```

Next, you need to list the states that are valid for objects of your `city_class`. For example, those might be "new", "saved", "updated", and "deleted".

For your objects to transition from one state to another, a certain event (or trigger) must happen. For example, when your object is first created, its state is new; when your object is saved to database, its state becomes "saved"; when the properties of the object are changed, its state becomes "updated"; and so on.

Notice that each transition requires an action to get into the next state; for example, the action of creation is required to reach the "new" state; the action of saving is required to reach the "saved" state; and so on. Therefore, you can make methods for your class out of those actions.

```
class city_class {
    var $saved;
    var $name;

    function __construct($name) {
        if (!$this->validate_city($name)) 
            throw new city_exception();
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function save() {
        $this->saved = true;
    }

    function update($new_name) {
        if (!$this->validate_city($new_name)) 
            throw new city_exception();
        $this->name = $new_name;
        $this->saved = false; // updated state
    }
}
```

In your comment, you list a responsibility of `city_class` as getting "id and name" from database--this is not proper OO design.

Your `city_class` knows only about itself and its collaborators at the *same level of abstraction*. Databases are at a different level of abstraction, and your `city_class` must not know about them. Therefore, for database access, you would need a `city_db` class that would be responsible for retrieving data and building `city_class` objects. Again, you follow the same process of identifying invariants and states of `city_db`, and making methods out of the events that cause transitions from one state to another.